# Transforming complex strings into simple arrays

Tags: javascript, optimization, sharepoint

Some time ago I wrote a series of functions for turning a string of user information from multiple users an array containing the information needed: Name, username and location. The raw `userinfo` string (`userinfo_raw`) looks like this:

```
1074;#Fring,, Gustavo (US - New Mexico),#i:0ǵ.t|adfs|gfring,#gfring@LPH.com,#gfring@lph.com,#Fring,, Gustavo (US - New Mexico);#11903;#Rodarte-Quaylet,, Lydia (US - Houston),#i:0#.w|atrema\lrquaylet,#lrquaylet@madrigal.com,#,#,, Rodarte-Quaylet,, Lydia (US - Houston)
```

My first problem was that users are separated with "#;", but this separator is also used within each user, separating the user ID from the rest of the information. I do not need the user ID, so I went overboard and made an entire function (`selfToArray`) to separate the user ID from the rest of the data.

```
var userinfoArray = new Array();    
var filterArray = new Array(); 
selfToArray( author_raw, filterArray ) //separate ID, keep the rest in the new array
if (filterArray.length > 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < (filterArray.length); i++) {
        author_data = filterArray[i].name
        getAuthor(author_data, userinfoArray, tile_AuthorArray_total)
    }
}

function selfToArray(input, inputArray, splitter) {
    if ( input ) {
        var input_id = ''
        var input_name = ''
        var splitby = ';'
        if (typeof splitter != 'undefined') splitby = splitter              
        if (input.indexOf( splitby ) >= 0) {
            var input_split_array = input.split( splitby )
            var input_split_array_length = input_split_array.length
            if (input_split_array_length > 1) {
                var second_value = input_split_array[1]
                var second_value_first_char = second_value.charAt(0)
                var second_value_second_char = second_value.charAt(1)
                if (second_value_first_char == '#') {
                    var number_check = isNaN(second_value_second_char) //it is a hash, and second char is not a number
                    for (var i = 0; i < input_split_array_length; i++) {
                        var this_id = ''
                        var name = ''
                        if (i % 2 == 0) { //check if even
                            this_id = input_split_array[i]
                            this_id = this_id.replace('#', '')
                            input_id = this_id
                        } 
                        else { //odd
                            name = input_split_array[i]
                            name = name.replace('#', '')
                            input_name = name
                            inputArray.push({
                                id: input_id,
                                name: input_name
                            });

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}   

function getAuthor(input, inputArray, totalArray ) { 
    var this_name = ''
    var this_login = ''
    var this_email = ''
    var this_username = ''
    var this_SIP = ''
    var this_login = '' 
    var this_location = ''  
    if (input.indexOf( ',,' ) >= 0) {
        input = input.replace(/,,/g, 'dummyvalue');
    }
    var arr = input.split(',#')
    for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i].indexOf("dummyvalue") >= 0) {    
            arr[i] = arr[i].replace('dummyvalue',',')                       
            if (arr[i].indexOf(" (") >= 0) {
                this_name = arr[i].split(' (')[0]
                this_location = arr[i].split(' (')[1] 
            }
            else {
                this_name = arr[i][0]                                   
            }
        }
        else if (arr[i].indexOf("@") >= 0) {
            this_email = arr[i]
            this_SIP = arr[i]
            this_username = arr[i].split('@')[0].toLowerCase()
        }
        else if (arr[i].indexOf("adfs") >= 0) {
            this_login = arr[i]
        }
    }
    inputArray.push({
        name: this_name,
        login: this_login,
        email: this_email,
        username: this_username,
        SIP: this_SIP,
        location: this_location
    });
    totalArray.push( this_name );               
}
```

I've learned enough to know that this is very, very far from an elegant way of doing this, but I am not certain of the optimal approach. I assume that first `selfToArray()` function should be easy to replace with either a regex filter or a simple loop, depending on what runs fastest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a once over:

- Read this about the [arrow pattern code](http://blog.codinghorror.com/flattening-arrow-code/), more specifically, your check on `input` should read like this:

  ```
  if( !input ) {
    return; //Or, you could even throw an error / exception ?
  }
  ```
- This can be shortened with the OR operator:

  ```
  var splitby = ';'
  if (typeof splitter != 'undefined') splitby = splitter
  ```

  to

  ```
  var splitby = splitter || ';'
  ```
- `input_split_array_length` has the same length `input_split_array.length` and you use it only twice. Either give it a shorter name, or don't create that variable at all.
- You could replace all these

  ```
  var this_name = ''
  var this_login = ''
  var this_email = ''
  var this_username = ''
  var this_SIP = ''
  var this_login = '' 
  var this_location = ''
  ```

  with

  ```
  var author = {};
  ```

  and then simply use `author.name` instead of `this_name`. Similarly you can then replace your push statement with `inputArray.push( author );`
- Semicolons, use them
- `var userinfoArray = new Array();` -> `var userinfoArray = []` , which is more idiomatic
- `this_login` is declared twice
- You are declaring `i` in the global namespace here: `for (i = 0; i < (filterArray.length); i++) {` , use a tool like jshint.com to detect this and fix this
- You determine `number_check` but you never use it
- Naming

  - `second_value_first_char` -> `secondValueFirstChar` <- Use lowerCamelCase
  - As names go, `secondValueFirstChar` is kind of terrible, think about shorter more meaningfull names
- Commenting, you dont have a lot of it, one comment is hard to understand and they all deserve their own line I think

Overall, I think you should take the above into account and rewrite large portions. Then, I would resubmit your re-factored code, because I think I only scratched the surface.

Comment: This. Also worth mentioning is line 4; `if (filterArray.length > 0) {` can be rewritten as `if (filterArray.length) {`.